# what does the output of 3D delaunay triangulation represent?

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I want to know what does the ConnectivityList in Delaunay triangulation in Matlab represent? Why does it have 4 columns?

Comment: I would assume they are index references for the 4 vertices of each tetrahedron that delaunay finds in 3D. I'm sure on of the other outputs will be a long 3 column matrix and you use that 4 column matrix to index the rows of the 3 column matrix if you want the x-y-z coords of any vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Matlab's delaunayTriangulation class documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html),
the `ConnectivityList` is a *triangulation connectivity list represented as a matrix*. 
Each row of the matrix corresponds to a tetrahedron (for 3D), or a triangle (for 2D).
Each element in the row is one of 4 vertex IDs of the tetrahedron (or for 2D, one of 3 vertex IDs of the triangle), a vertex ID being the row number of one of the points you provided to `delaunayTriangulation()`.